# Basic Set Notation - Question on Defining a Set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

$$\mathcal{S} = \{1, 2, ..., k\};\,  k \in \mathbb{N}$$,

Let's say $k = 1$, would the set $\mathcal{S}$ be $\{1, 2, 1\} = \{1, 2\}$ or would it be $\{1,1\} = \{1\}$.

In other words, I know that the 1, 2 is there in the definition to establish that you start at 1 and go up to $k$ by increments of 1. Is the 2 there only to establish this fact, or does its presence mean it must be in any set $\mathcal{S}$?

Comment: When $k=1$ the notation is meant to tell you that $S=\{1\}$. The dots tell you it's informal, and may be a little confusing in edge cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, the $2$ is only suggestive of the pattern. It's not in the set if $k < 2$.

A more precise version of $\{1,2,...,k\}$ would be $\{x \in \mathbb{Z}\mid 1 \le x \le k\}$.

Answer (score 1):

When $k=1$ the notation is meant to tell you that $S=\{1\}$. The dots tell you it's informal, and may be a little confusing in edge cases.

A formal way to write that definition would be
$$
S = \{ n \in \mathbb{N} \ | \ 1 \le n \le k \}.
$$

That would even give the right answer when $k=0$: the empty set.

We write the informal definition because it's easier to read.